# Making a large image smaller using CSS (downscaling) results in blurry images in IE9, FF, but fine in Chrome

Tags: css

I'm using the following css to display a 661px x 343px image:

```
width: 95px; height:auto;
```

I have found that using the following CSS will give the same blurriness in Chrome:

```
image-rendering:-webkit-optimize-contrast;
```

So deleting the above makes the image much clearer in chrome, any idea how to fix the problem for the other browsers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally you shouldn't do this, reason being is the user will download the larger image.

Imagine you have a 2Mb image you want to show on a website, the user would have to download the 2Mb file just to view the smaller image.  It is best practice to resize the image and create a thumbnail link.

As for the issue it is the browser rendering that is the issue, As far as I know there is no alternative to this.

Comment: The images are already displayed in the larger format on the same page as the thumbnails, so I thought it would be better to avoid extra images by using css.  But I guess it's the only solution to the problem to add the resized images.

Comment: Sadly so Lawrence, but it would be easier to show the thumbnail and save bandwidth and make the site faster than it would to show the large image, faster site = better search engine ranks = better support for mobiles = happy systems administrator :)

Comment: Exept that there are plenty of times when this is desirable (to downscale an image into a smaller area), and that stil doesn't answer the question: how to get downsampled images to display anti-aliased correctly and not be jaggy or blurry.  And since he is already displaying the larger image on the page anyway, then your answer is worse for page performance to also have to d/l thumbs, since that involvs double the number of http requests the browser has to manage.

Answer (score 1):

resize the source image to the correct width and height, then you won't have any issues displaying it across browsers